# php-fpm start error

Tags: php

I am using php-fpm. I recently recompiled php for including imap functions. But on php-fpm start it gives the following error:

> Starting php_fpm Error in argument 1,
>   char 1: no argument for option -
>   Usage: php-cgi [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v]
>   [-i] [-f ] php-cgi [args...]
>   -a Run
>   interactively
>   -C Do not chdir to the
>   script's directory
>   -c | Look for
>   php.ini file in this directory
>   -n No php.ini file will be used
>   -d foo[=bar]
>   Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
>   -e Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
>   -f Parse . Implies
>   `-q'
>   -h This help -i PHP information
>   -l Syntax check only (lint)
>   -m Show compiled in modules 
>   -q Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP Header output.
>   -s Display colour syntax highlighted source.
>   -v Version number
>   -w Display
>   source with stripped comments and
>   whitespace.
>   -z Load Zend extension
>   ...................................
>   failed

What could be the problem? Is it in php-fpm.conf or php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

You need reconfigure and recompile php sources.
Remember about `make clean` if you do it again and again.
Php-fpm patch for php 5.2 branch can be download from here: http://php-fpm.org/
5.3 and 5.4 branch has php-fpm included.

Crucial options for compiling php 5.2 with php-fpm:

```
--enable-fastcgi --enable-fpm --enable-force-cgi-redirect
```

Location of php-fpm.conf depends on your prefix.
If you chose `/usr/local/` it should be in `/usr/local/etc` in case of 5.2

For php 5.3 and 5.4:

```
--enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=http --with-fpm-group=http
```

Group and user fit only for my distro. Use proper for yours.

For my installation of 5.4 I chose `--sysconfdir=/etc/php54`
so php-fpm.conf it's just right there.

Comment: Worked for me (php 5.2.17 + fpm patch)

Answer (score 0):

When i reinstall php, the config file for php-fpm is located at /usr/etc/, however the old poisition is at /etc. After copying php-fpm.conf from /etc to /usr/etc php-fpm works again.

Answer (score 0):

> **argument 1**, **char 1**: no argument for option **-**

Note the "-" at the end.

How do you run it?

Any changes in startup script? Post the startup script (pastebin.com), also, how did you compile it.

Hope you've used src.rpm ([CentOS - PHP - Yum Install with Custom ./configure params](https://serverfault.com/questions/395922/centos-php-yum-install-with-custom-configure-params/399036#399036))