# Install sqlite latest version on Centos6.7

Tags: centos6, installation, yum, sqlite

I'm trying to install the latests versions of sqlite (**> 3.7.5**) under *Centos 6.7*.

So when I launch `install` command :

```
yum install sqlite
```

I get the following Message :

> Package sqlite-3.6.20-1.el6_7.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   
>   Nothing to do

**Question :** How can I install the latest version of *sqlite* in *Centos6.7*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried this locally just now and it's work, now I have sqlite3.10.0 installed on centos6.7 :

1. Download last version of sqlite from : **http://www.sqlite.org/download.html**.

   Or on the server using : **wget http://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-autoconf-3100000.tar.gz**.
2. unzip it : tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3100000.tar.gz
3. cd sqlite-autoconf-3100000
4. ./configure
5. make
6. make install
7. last step if you're using *sqlite3* in php, you should recompile it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @GioMac Why "NEVER"? I've done `configure`, `make`, `make install` on thousands of machines and never had a problem.

Comment: @jerzy congratulations on doing things not right on thousands of machines :)

Comment: @GioMac You didn't answer the question. Why "NEVER"?

Comment: @jerzy because you break dependencies. packages exist not for easy installations, they ensure, that dependencies cannot be broken.

Comment: @GioMac How does running `configure`, `make`, or `make install` break dependencies?

Comment: @jerzy What does it mean how does it break? That's what it does, naturally. What are the dependencies then?

Comment: @GioMac It looks like you deleted your comment where you said to "NEVER" run `configure`, `make`, and `make install` on production servers.

Comment: @jerzy, nope, i didn't, probably admin did

Comment: I needed an updated version sqlite for python/django. It won't work in python unless you add `/usr/local/lib` to the ld library path like this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

Comment: This is so clunky... it doesn't install properly

Answer (score 2):

Correct way will be to rebuild rpm with never version, but best way is to have it as separate package to maintain compatibility with old version: https://serverfault.com/a/399036/102979